# Export HTML in a java to PDF

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts, itextpdf

I'm trying to export some auto generated HTML that is in a JavaScript var with iTextPdf in the java code, but I don't know how it works, because I've got an String in the var and I don't know how to Export it.
This is my HTML code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">Filtros de Busqueda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Proveedor</td>
        <td colspan="14">OCA - OCA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Sector</td>
        <td colspan="14">Sin Sector Â </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

All this code in in a javascript var I'm sending it by a submit and in the action I'm doing this

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new           FileOutputStream(filePath + fileName + ".pdf"));
document.open();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(buffer);             
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, reader);
document.close();
pdfWriter.close();
pdfWriter = null;
System.gc();               

response.setContentType("application/vnd.pdf"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "." + fileType
                 + "\"");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(buffer);
out.close();
```

For some reason this isn't working, my first tought was that it can't convert an string. 
Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Your Html is lacking body-tags

Comment: IS your DOCUMENT blank ?

Comment: Is really has body tags

Comment: Have you checked that buffer contains the things you expect it to contain?

Comment: Yes, the var buffer contains the String for export.